# general facebook question about graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I understand that an access token is needed to access an individuals private content when using the graph api. What is considered private in a fan page and do you need an access token to access all fan page content? When running a word search with type=posts in the graph api we expect only public content, is this the same for fan page searches and if not, is there really any need to have an access token when searching the graph api?

I have not finished my app yet but when just plugging into a browser
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post
that works so why would I need to register my app. Should this not work if I set up a webrequest method?

Answer (score 0):

Registering an app doesn't hurt, its easy and if something was to go wrong, they will suspend/ban your app ID rather than your server's IP. Better IMHO!